# Compare the relationship of two objects with a third object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, relationship

I'm looking for a way to find which of two objects is the closest relation to a third object in terms of the DOM Tree order, not the pixels.

The two objects requiring comparison could appear anywhere on the DOM, relative to the object I wish to compare them with.

Comment: Do you mean closest in terms of pixels, or closest in terms of parent/child structure?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by closest relation? Maybe distance on the screen or distance in the DOM tree?

Comment: the later, the nearest in the DOM structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that object is Node then you can always use

#### Absolute position

```
/*
     compare each node in nodes to target. The node that's closest to target
     will be returned. closest is defined as absolute x,y distance between 
     the top, left corner of two nodes
*/
function whichIsCloser(nodes, target) {
    var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect()

    return nodes.reduce(function (prev, current) {
        var prevRect = prev.getBoundingClientRect(),
            currentRect = current.getBoundingClientRect(),
            prevDistance = Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(prevRect.left - rect.left, 2) + 
                Math.pow(prevRect.top - rect.top, 2)
            ),
            currentDistance = Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(currentRect.left - rect.left, 2) +
                Math.pow(currentRect.top - rect.top, 2)
            )

        return prevDistance < currentDistance ? prev : current
    })
}
```

#### dom tree position

Using [`iterativelyWalk`](https://gist.github.com/1473536#file_iterate_walk.js)

```
/*
     compare nodes to target. The node that's closest to target will be returned
     closest is defined as getting an array of all nodes in tree order and 
     returning the node who's index offset in the array wrt the target
     is the smallest.
*/
function whichIsCloser(nodes, target) {
    var allNodes = []
    iterativelyWalk(document.documentElement.childNodes, function (node) {
        allNodes.push(node)
    })
    return nodes.reduce(function (prev, current) {
        var prevDistance = Math.abs(allNodes.indexOf(prev) - allNodes.indexOf(target)),
            currentDistance = Math.abs(allNodes.indexOf(current) - allNodes.indexOf(target))

        return prevDistance < currentDistance ? prev : current
    })
}
```

Comment: sorry, I mean in terms of the DOM structure, not the pixels

Comment: @MildFuzz DOM structure is very vague. I put up a solution that tells you which is closest in tree order

Comment: @Raynos, what exactly do your samples do?

Comment: @Raynos, the first sample surely does not return the closest element in absolute position. About the second one, I don't have the time to wonder what exactly found1, found2, found3 are used for, why you use closure and why you pollute the global namespace in iterativelyWalk.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand, but do you mean the actual closeness in terms of DOM elements between them in the tree?

If so, here's something to do that (probably not the fastest, but it seems to work):

```
var count = 1;
$('*').each(function() {
    $(this).data('count', count);
    count++;
});

var first = $("#firstobject").data('count'),
    second = $("#secondobject").data('count'),
    third = $("#thirdobject").data('count'),
    tofirst = third>first ? third-first : Math.abs(third-first),
    tosecond = third>second ? third-second : Math.abs(third-second);

if (tofirst<tosecond) {
    alert('first is closer than second to third');
}else{
    alert('second is closer than first to third');
}​
```

And here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/HUe7R/)

Comment: That's horribly inefficient, also how is `$("*")` ordered?

Comment: I agree, it's not efficient at all, but it was the easiest solution I could come up with, and it seems jQuery starts at the top and applies the count downwards in the DOM, so it does seem to work. A better solution in jQuery atleast, would probably be to get the HTML of the document into a a variable and somehow count elements between the given elements or something like that without applying stuff to every DOM element.